# Not able to execute service restart, copy file from non root user in ansible

Tags: ansible

```
---
  - hosts: all
    become_user: ansible
    become: yes
    become_method: sudo
    tasks:
      - name: Restart the sshd service
        service: name=sshd state=restarted

### sudoers file entry for user on host ####
ansible ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:ALL


PLAY [all] ***************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************
ok: [host2.domain.local]
ok: [host1.domain.local]

TASK [Restart the ssh service] *******************************************************
fatal: [host2.domain.local]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to restart service sshd: Failed to restart sshd.service: Interactive authentication required.\n"}
fatal: [host1.domain.local]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to restart service sshd: Failed to restart sshd.service: Interactive authentication required.\n"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/root/1stplay.retry

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************
host1.domain.local         : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   
host2.domain.local         : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lose the line:

```
become_user: ansible
```

Presumably you are logging into the target machine as ansible and want to become root, not ansible? If you do not specify the `become_user` root is used by default.